SharePoint Migration NT Authority \authenticated users is not working after migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019 on premise
Please help in getting this resolved During SharePoint Migration NT Authority \authenticated users is not working after migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019 on premise.
what type of change we need to check.
